# Can we make an object of an inner class inside a function without making an object of the main outer class

Tags: java, object, inner-classes

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

I am getting this error on running the code. Have i made the object of inner class in a wrong way?I want to compare the battery value of two objects so i have overridden the equals method.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    class SOC //inner class
    {
     int x, y;
     SOC(int x,int y)
     {
         this.x=x;
         this.y=y;
     }
       @Override public boolean equals(Object obj)// equals function will compare the battery values of
       //the two objects
    {
        
        SOC i1 = (SOC)obj;//type casting object to the
                           // intended class type
 
        
        if ((this.battery-i1.battery)>1)
        return true;
       // return this.name.equals(p1.name)
         //   && this.age == p1.age;
    }
    }
    SOC ob=new SOC(0,0);//call this obj inside func
    public void func()
    {
        int battery=sc.nextInt();
        int time=sc.nextInt();
       SOC inner=new SOC(battery,time);//making object of inner class  
       if(ob.battery!=0&&ob.time!=0)
      System.out.println(inner.equals (ob));
    ob=inner;
      
        
        
    }
      public static void main (String[] args) {
     Main ot=new Main();
     ot.func();
     ot.func();
 }   
}
```

Comment: You have two fields `x` and `y` in your `SOC` class, yet you try to use `battery` and `time` in your other code. Is this the actual code you're trying to run? Also your `equals` method doesn't `return` in all cases. But instantiation of `SOC` itself is not wrong.

Comment: plus what JoachimSauer said battery and time are local filed so you can not access them from outside their scope (from outside the func method in your case) and for your post subject question yes you can make your inner class static

Comment: check this for tutorial about inner class https://dev.java/learn/classes-objects/nested-classes/